# Is there a web-embeddable skin preview application?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I'm working on a website for my Minecraft server, and we're looking at creating pages for each of the admins/mods, with some info about them.  I'm trying to find a way that I can embed a 'skin preview' of each player's skin onto their respective pages.  I suppose we could also just use screenshots, but I think a skin preview would look nicer.  Any suggestions?

---

**Edit:**
[This website](http://www.planetminecraft.com/skin/dirt-18381/) uses a Java applet, but I'm not 100% sure how to implement this myself.

Comment: Doesn't Minecraft.net already have this? Actually, I think they only have the "change your skin", you have to know what you want to change it too first.

Comment: @Raven > It looks like there USED to be one on the website, but it's not there anymore.  I've found some places that use a 3D java applet created by notch; I'm guessing this is the one that used to be on minecraft.net

Comment: I guess it's time to create a Flash app to do that. If I have time I'll make one and post it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about website development, not playing games.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Minecraft.net](http://minecraft.net/) *does* have a skin viewer available, as long as you're only trying to view existing users' current skins rather than previewing them straight from `.png` files.  To invoke it, add the following code to your page:

```
<applet code="net.minecraft.skintest.ModelPreviewApplet"
  archive="http://www.minecraft.net/skin/skintest.jar" codebase="."
  width="320" height="320">
    <param name="name" value="535" />
</applet>
```

(Change `535` to whatever username you want to view.)  I've set up an [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jVtyu/).

If you want to preview arbitrary skins, the applet used by Planet Minecraft *appears* to be available for public use (it points to a [forum post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?t=4843), though that thread doesn't appear to mention PMC's previewer).  Still, I'd recommend sending them an email first, just in case.

Comment: Works excellent, but this doesn't show every layer of the skin (accessory layers don't appear to show up), so I'm going to hold off on accepting it for now, unless another solution comes up.

Comment: Is there anything like this where instead of a username I'd refer to a .png?

Comment: http://www.minecraft.net/skin/skintest.jar seems to be gone now. Where do we reference skintest.jar now?